SVG animation diagramm
I wanted to animate a graphic. It should be like an diagramm loader. I dont know what i need to type in so it starts where the diagramm starts and not before.
I once made a diagramm loader so i decided to pretty much use the same code.
Here is the code for the diagramm loader:


<div class="loader loader--style4" title="3">
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;" xml:space="preserve">
    
   
    <rect x="0" y="5" width="5" height="40" fill="#333">
      <animateTransform  attributeType="xml"
        attributeName="transform" type="scale"
        values="1,1; 1,3; 1,1"
        begin="0s" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />       
    </rect>

    <rect x="10" y="5" width="5" height="40" fill="#333">
      <animateTransform  attributeType="xml"
        attributeName="transform" type="scale"
        values="1,1; 1,3; 1,1"
        begin="0.2s" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />       
    </rect>
    <rect x="20" y="5" width="5" height="40" fill="#333">
      <animateTransform  attributeType="xml"
        attributeName="transform" type="scale"
        values="1,1; 1,3; 1,1"
        begin="0.4s" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />       
    </rect>
  </svg>
</div>



Here is my attempt on using the same code in my graphic.


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 758 230">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: #2a2b2c;
        stroke-width: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g id="Geldmünzen">
    <g id="Münzen_links" data-name="Münzen links">
      <path class="cls-1" d="m260.03,220.54c0,5.36-11.37,9.71-25.39,9.71s-25.39-4.35-25.39-9.71c0-.71.2-1.42.59-2.09,5.66,3.98,15.46,5.85,24.8,5.85s19.15-1.87,24.8-5.85c.39.67.59,1.38.59,2.09Z"/>
      <path class="cls-1" d="m260.03,210.39c0,.71-.2,1.41-.59,2.08-.33.58-.79,1.13-1.38,1.67-.5.46-1.1.9-1.77,1.32-4.46,2.78-12.49,4.64-21.66,4.64s-17.19-1.86-21.66-4.64c-.67-.42-1.27-.86-1.77-1.32-.59-.54-1.05-1.09-1.38-1.67-.39-.67-.59-1.36-.59-2.08s.2-1.42.6-2.09c1.1.78,2.35,1.47,3.73,2.09.93.41,1.92.79,2.95,1.13,1.15.39,2.37.73,3.63,1.04,4.51,1.06,9.56,1.59,14.49,1.59s9.97-.52,14.49-1.59c1.26-.3,2.48-.65,3.63-1.04,1.03-.35,2.02-.72,2.95-1.13,1.38-.62,2.62-1.31,3.73-2.09.4.67.6,1.38.6,2.09Z"/>
      <path class="cls-1" d="m260.03,200.23c0,.71-.2,1.42-.59,2.09-.33.58-.79,1.13-1.38,1.67-.5.46-1.1.9-1.78,1.32-1.84,1.15-4.28,2.14-7.16,2.9-1.72.47-3.57.85-5.56,1.13h-.02c-2.77.39-5.77.61-8.9.61s-6.13-.22-8.9-.61h-.02c-1.99-.28-3.84-.66-5.56-1.13-2.88-.76-5.32-1.74-7.16-2.9-.68-.42-1.28-.86-1.78-1.32-.59-.54-1.05-1.09-1.38-1.67-.39-.67-.59-1.38-.59-2.09s.2-1.41.59-2.08c1.1.77,2.35,1.47,3.74,2.09.93.41,1.92.79,2.95,1.13,1.15.39,2.37.73,3.63,1.04,4.51,1.06,9.56,1.59,14.49,1.59s9.97-.52,14.49-1.59c1.26-.3,2.48-.65,3.63-1.04,1.03-.35,2.02-.72,2.95-1.13,1.39-.62,2.63-1.32,3.74-2.09.39.67.59,1.36.59,2.08Z"/>
      <path class="cls-1" d="m260.03,190.08c0,.71-.2,1.42-.59,2.09-.33.58-.8,1.13-1.39,1.67-.5.46-1.09.9-1.76,1.32-1.84,1.14-4.28,2.13-7.17,2.9-1.72.46-3.57.84-5.56,1.13h-.02c-2.77.39-5.77.61-8.9.61s-6.13-.22-8.9-.61h-.02c-1.99-.29-3.84-.67-5.56-1.13-2.89-.77-5.33-1.75-7.17-2.9-.67-.42-1.26-.86-1.76-1.32-.59-.54-1.06-1.09-1.39-1.67-.39-.67-.59-1.38-.59-2.09s.2-1.42.59-2.09c1.1.78,2.35,1.47,3.74,2.1.93.41,1.92.79,2.95,1.13,1.15.39,2.37.73,3.63,1.04,4.51,1.06,9.56,1.59,14.49,1.59s9.97-.52,14.49-1.59c1.26-.3,2.48-.65,3.63-1.04,1.03-.35,2.02-.72,2.95-1.13,1.39-.63,2.63-1.32,3.74-2.1.39.67.59,1.38.59,2.09Z"/>
      <path class="cls-1" d="m260.03,179.93c0,.71-.2,1.42-.6,2.09-.33.58-.79,1.13-1.38,1.67-.5.46-1.09.9-1.76,1.32-1.84,1.14-4.28,2.13-7.17,2.9-1.72.46-3.57.84-5.56,1.13h-.02c-2.77.39-5.77.61-8.9.61s-6.13-.22-8.9-.61h-.02c-1.99-.29-3.84-.67-5.56-1.13-2.89-.77-5.33-1.75-7.17-2.9-.67-.42-1.26-.86-1.76-1.32-.59-.54-1.05-1.09-1.38-1.67-.4-.67-.6-1.38-.6-2.09s.2-1.41.59-2.08c1.1.77,2.35,1.47,3.74,2.09.93.41,1.92.79,2.95,1.13,1.15.39,2.37.73,3.63,1.04,4.51,1.06,9.56,1.59,14.49,1.59s9.97-.52,14.49-1.59c1.26-.3,2.48-.65,3.63-1.04,1.03-.35,2.02-.72,2.95-1.13,1.39-.62,2.63-1.32,3.74-2.09.39.67.59,1.36.59,2.08Z"/>
      <path class="cls-1" d="m260.03,169.78c0,.71-.2,1.42-.59,2.09-.33.58-.79,1.13-1.38,1.66-.5.46-1.1.91-1.77,1.33-1.84,1.14-4.28,2.13-7.17,2.9-1.72.46-3.57.84-5.56,1.13h-.02c-2.77.39-5.77.61-8.9.61s-6.13-.22-8.9-.61h-.02c-1.99-.29-3.84-.67-5.56-1.13-2.89-.77-5.33-1.75-7.17-2.9-.67-.42-1.27-.87-1.77-1.33-.59-.52-1.05-1.08-1.38-1.66-.39-.67-.59-1.38-.59-2.09s.2-1.42.59-2.09c1.1.78,2.36,1.47,3.75,2.09.92.41,1.91.8,2.94,1.13,1.17.39,2.39.73,3.65,1.04,4.5,1.07,9.55,1.59,14.46,1.59s9.96-.51,14.46-1.59c1.26-.3,2.49-.65,3.65-1.04,1.03-.34,2.02-.72,2.94-1.13,1.39-.62,2.65-1.31,3.75-2.09.39.67.59,1.38.59,2.09Z"/>
      <path class="cls-1" d="m260.03,159.62c0,.71-.2,1.42-.6,2.09-.33.58-.79,1.13-1.36,1.66-.5.46-1.1.9-1.77,1.33-1.85,1.14-4.3,2.13-7.19,2.9-1.72.46-3.61.84-5.61,1.12-2.76.39-5.74.61-8.86.61s-6.1-.22-8.86-.61c-1.99-.28-3.88-.66-5.61-1.12-2.89-.77-5.34-1.75-7.19-2.9-.67-.43-1.27-.87-1.77-1.33-.58-.52-1.04-1.08-1.36-1.66-.4-.67-.6-1.38-.6-2.09,0-5.36,11.37-9.71,25.39-9.71s25.39,4.35,25.39,9.71Z"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Münzen_rechts" data-name="Münzen rechts">
      <path class="cls-1" d="m316.86,225.58c0,.71-.2,1.42-.59,2.09-.32.57-.8,1.13-1.38,1.67-.25.22-.51.44-.8.66h-45.25c-.29-.22-.55-.44-.79-.66-.59-.54-1.06-1.1-1.39-1.67-.39-.67-.59-1.38-.59-2.09s.2-1.42.59-2.09c1.1.78,2.35,1.47,3.74,2.1.93.41,1.92.79,2.95,1.13,1.15.39,2.37.74,3.63,1.04,4.51,1.06,9.56,1.59,14.49,1.59s9.97-.53,14.48-1.59c1.26-.3,2.48-.65,3.63-1.04,1.03-.34,2.02-.72,2.95-1.13,1.39-.63,2.64-1.32,3.74-2.1.39.67.59,1.37.59,2.09Z"/>
      <path class="cls-1" d="m316.86,215.43c0,.71-.2,1.42-.6,2.09-.33.58-.79,1.13-1.38,1.67-.5.46-1.09.9-1.76,1.32-1.84,1.14-4.28,2.13-7.17,2.9-1.72.46-3.57.84-5.56,1.13h-.02c-2.77.39-5.77.61-8.9.61s-6.13-.22-8.9-.61h-.02c-1.99-.29-3.84-.67-5.56-1.13-2.89-.77-5.33-1.75-7.17-2.9-.67-.42-1.26-.86-1.76-1.32-.59-.54-1.05-1.09-1.38-1.67-.4-.67-.6-1.38-.6-2.09s.2-1.41.59-2.08c1.1.77,2.35,1.47,3.74,2.09.93.41,1.92.79,2.95,1.13,1.15.39,2.37.73,3.63,1.04,4.51,1.06,9.56,1.59,14.49,1.59s9.97-.52,14.49-1.59c1.26-.3,2.48-.65,3.63-1.04,1.03-.35,2.02-.72,2.95-1.13,1.39-.62,2.63-1.32,3.74-2.09.39.67.59,1.36.59,2.08Z"/>
      <path class="cls-1" d="m316.86,205.28c0,.71-.2,1.42-.59,2.09-.33.58-.79,1.13-1.38,1.66-.5.46-1.1.91-1.77,1.33-1.84,1.14-4.28,2.13-7.17,2.9-1.72.46-3.57.84-5.56,1.13h-.02c-2.77.39-5.77.61-8.9.61s-6.13-.22-8.9-.61h-.02c-1.99-.29-3.84-.67-5.56-1.13-2.89-.77-5.33-1.75-7.17-2.9-.67-.42-1.27-.87-1.77-1.33-.59-.52-1.05-1.08-1.38-1.66-.39-.67-.59-1.38-.59-2.09s.2-1.42.59-2.09c1.1.78,2.36,1.47,3.75,2.09.92.41,1.91.8,2.94,1.13,1.17.39,2.39.73,3.65,1.04,4.5,1.07,9.55,1.59,14.46,1.59s9.96-.51,14.46-1.59c1.26-.3,2.49-.65,3.65-1.04,1.03-.34,2.02-.72,2.94-1.13,1.39-.62,2.65-1.31,3.75-2.09.39.67.59,1.38.59,2.09Z"/>
      <path class="cls-1" d="m316.86,195.13c0,.71-.2,1.42-.6,2.09-.33.58-.79,1.13-1.36,1.66-.5.46-1.1.9-1.77,1.33-1.85,1.14-4.3,2.13-7.19,2.9-1.72.46-3.61.84-5.61,1.12-2.76.39-5.74.61-8.86.61s-6.1-.22-8.86-.61c-1.99-.28-3.88-.66-5.61-1.12-2.89-.77-5.34-1.75-7.19-2.9-.67-.43-1.27-.87-1.77-1.33-.58-.52-1.04-1.08-1.36-1.66-.4-.67-.6-1.38-.6-2.09,0-5.36,11.37-9.71,25.39-9.71s25.39,4.35,25.39,9.71Z"/>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g id="Bank">
    <path id="Bank-2" data-name="Bank" class="cls-1" d="m448.71,167.05l-49.85-23.93c-2.27-1.09-4.92-1.09-7.2,0l-49.8,23.93c-2.01.96-1.32,3.97.9,3.97h4.12v.15l.02.7c.03,1.14.96,2.04,2.09,2.04h1.21c1.16,0,2.1.93,2.1,2.09v42.99c0,1.55-1.26,2.8-2.8,2.8h-2.35c-1.52,0-2.76,1.24-2.76,2.76v3.06c0,1.54,1.25,2.78,2.79,2.78h96.27c1.52,0,2.74-1.23,2.74-2.75v-4.71c0-1.53-1.23-2.77-2.76-2.77h-1.22c-1.52,0-2.75-1.23-2.75-2.76l.21-42.09c.01-1.16.95-2.09,2.1-2.09.58,0,1.1-.24,1.49-.62.37-.38.6-.9.6-1.48v-.1h3.95c2.22,0,2.91-3.01.9-3.97Zm-72.01,51.49c0,1.16-.94,2.09-2.09,2.09h-10.92c-1.16,0-2.11-.93-2.11-2.09v-42.54c0-1.16.95-2.09,2.11-2.09h10.92c1.15,0,2.09.93,2.09,2.09v42.54Zm26.26,0c0,1.16-.93,2.09-2.09,2.09h-10.93c-1.15,0-2.09-.93-2.09-2.09v-42.54c0-1.16.94-2.09,2.09-2.09h10.93c1.16,0,2.09.93,2.09,2.09v42.54Zm25.68,0c0,1.16-.93,2.09-2.09,2.09h-10.92c-1.16,0-2.09-.93-2.09-2.09v-42.54c0-1.16.93-2.09,2.09-2.09h10.92c1.16,0,2.09.93,2.09,2.09v42.54Z"/>
  </g>
  <g id="Wolkenkratzer">
    <path id="Wolkenkratzer-2" data-name="Wolkenkratzer" class="cls-1" d="m563.63,102.66h-27c-3.8,0-6.91,3.12-6.91,6.92v24.88h-14.67v-25.16c0-3.65-2.99-6.64-6.64-6.64h-27.55c-3.65,0-6.64,2.99-6.64,6.64v120.77h15v-9.07c0-1.66,1.36-3.02,3.02-3.02h4.79c1.66,0,3.02,1.36,3.02,3.02v9.07h15v-80.71h14.67v80.71h15v-9.07c0-1.66,1.35-3.02,3.02-3.02h4.79c1.66,0,3.02,1.36,3.02,3.02v9.07h14.99v-120.49c0-3.8-3.11-6.92-6.91-6.92Zm-79.34,107.31c0,1.08-.89,1.97-1.97,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.96-.89-1.96-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.88-1.97,1.96-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.97.89,1.97,1.97v6.16Zm0-15.5c0,1.09-.89,1.97-1.97,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.96-.88-1.96-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.88-1.96,1.96-1.96h.12c1.08,0,1.97.88,1.97,1.96v6.16Zm0-15.49c0,1.08-.89,1.96-1.97,1.96h-.12c-1.08,0-1.96-.88-1.96-1.96v-6.17c0-1.08.88-1.96,1.96-1.96h.12c1.08,0,1.97.88,1.97,1.96v6.17Zm0-15.5c0,1.08-.89,1.97-1.97,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.96-.89-1.96-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.88-1.97,1.96-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.97.89,1.97,1.97v6.16Zm0-15.5c0,1.08-.89,1.97-1.97,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.96-.89-1.96-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.88-1.97,1.96-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.97.89,1.97,1.97v6.16Zm0-15.49c0,1.08-.89,1.96-1.97,1.96h-.12c-1.08,0-1.96-.88-1.96-1.96v-6.17c0-1.08.88-1.96,1.96-1.96h.12c1.08,0,1.97.88,1.97,1.96v6.17Zm0-15.5c0,1.08-.89,1.96-1.97,1.96h-.12c-1.08,0-1.96-.88-1.96-1.96v-6.16c0-1.08.88-1.97,1.96-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.97.89,1.97,1.97v6.16Zm8.25,92.98c0,1.08-.89,1.97-1.97,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.96-.89-1.96-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.88-1.97,1.96-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.97.89,1.97,1.97v6.16Zm0-15.5c0,1.09-.89,1.97-1.97,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.96-.88-1.96-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.88-1.96,1.96-1.96h.12c1.08,0,1.97.88,1.97,1.96v6.16Zm0-15.49c0,1.08-.89,1.96-1.97,1.96h-.12c-1.08,0-1.96-.88-1.96-1.96v-6.17c0-1.08.88-1.96,1.96-1.96h.12c1.08,0,1.97.88,1.97,1.96v6.17Zm0-15.5c0,1.08-.89,1.97-1.97,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.96-.89-1.96-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.88-1.97,1.96-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.97.89,1.97,1.97v6.16Zm0-15.5c0,1.08-.89,1.97-1.97,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.96-.89-1.96-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.88-1.97,1.96-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.97.89,1.97,1.97v6.16Zm0-15.49c0,1.08-.89,1.96-1.97,1.96h-.12c-1.08,0-1.96-.88-1.96-1.96v-6.17c0-1.08.88-1.96,1.96-1.96h.12c1.08,0,1.97.88,1.97,1.96v6.17Zm0-15.5c0,1.08-.89,1.96-1.97,1.96h-.12c-1.08,0-1.96-.88-1.96-1.96v-6.16c0-1.08.88-1.97,1.96-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.97.89,1.97,1.97v6.16Zm8.24,92.98c0,1.08-.88,1.97-1.96,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.89-1.97-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.89-1.97,1.97-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.96.89,1.96,1.97v6.16Zm0-15.5c0,1.09-.88,1.97-1.96,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.88-1.97-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.89-1.96,1.97-1.96h.12c1.08,0,1.96.88,1.96,1.96v6.16Zm0-15.49c0,1.08-.88,1.96-1.96,1.96h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.88-1.97-1.96v-6.17c0-1.08.89-1.96,1.97-1.96h.12c1.08,0,1.96.88,1.96,1.96v6.17Zm0-15.5c0,1.08-.88,1.97-1.96,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.89-1.97-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.89-1.97,1.97-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.96.89,1.96,1.97v6.16Zm0-15.5c0,1.08-.88,1.97-1.96,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.89-1.97-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.89-1.97,1.97-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.96.89,1.96,1.97v6.16Zm0-15.49c0,1.08-.88,1.96-1.96,1.96h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.88-1.97-1.96v-6.17c0-1.08.89-1.96,1.97-1.96h.12c1.08,0,1.96.88,1.96,1.96v6.17Zm0-15.5c0,1.08-.88,1.96-1.96,1.96h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.88-1.97-1.96v-6.16c0-1.08.89-1.97,1.97-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.96.89,1.96,1.97v6.16Zm8.25,92.98c0,1.08-.88,1.97-1.96,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.89-1.97-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.89-1.97,1.97-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.96.89,1.96,1.97v6.16Zm0-15.5c0,1.09-.88,1.97-1.96,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.88-1.97-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.89-1.96,1.97-1.96h.12c1.08,0,1.96.88,1.96,1.96v6.16Zm0-15.49c0,1.08-.88,1.96-1.96,1.96h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.88-1.97-1.96v-6.17c0-1.08.89-1.96,1.97-1.96h.12c1.08,0,1.96.88,1.96,1.96v6.17Zm0-15.5c0,1.08-.88,1.97-1.96,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.89-1.97-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.89-1.97,1.97-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.96.89,1.96,1.97v6.16Zm0-15.5c0,1.08-.88,1.97-1.96,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.89-1.97-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.89-1.97,1.97-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.96.89,1.96,1.97v6.16Zm0-15.49c0,1.08-.88,1.96-1.96,1.96h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.88-1.97-1.96v-6.17c0-1.08.89-1.96,1.97-1.96h.12c1.08,0,1.96.88,1.96,1.96v6.17Zm0-15.5c0,1.08-.88,1.96-1.96,1.96h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.88-1.97-1.96v-6.16c0-1.08.89-1.97,1.97-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.96.89,1.96,1.97v6.16Zm30.75,92.98c0,1.08-.88,1.97-1.96,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.89-1.97-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.89-1.97,1.97-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.96.89,1.96,1.97v6.16Zm0-15.5c0,1.09-.88,1.97-1.96,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.88-1.97-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.89-1.96,1.97-1.96h.12c1.08,0,1.96.88,1.96,1.96v6.16Zm0-15.49c0,1.08-.88,1.96-1.96,1.96h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.88-1.97-1.96v-6.17c0-1.08.89-1.96,1.97-1.96h.12c1.08,0,1.96.88,1.96,1.96v6.17Zm0-15.5c0,1.08-.88,1.97-1.96,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.89-1.97-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.89-1.97,1.97-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.96.89,1.96,1.97v6.16Zm0-15.5c0,1.08-.88,1.97-1.96,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.89-1.97-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.89-1.97,1.97-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.96.89,1.96,1.97v6.16Zm0-15.49c0,1.08-.88,1.96-1.96,1.96h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.88-1.97-1.96v-6.17c0-1.08.89-1.96,1.97-1.96h.12c1.08,0,1.96.88,1.96,1.96v6.17Zm0-15.5c0,1.08-.88,1.96-1.96,1.96h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.88-1.97-1.96v-6.16c0-1.08.89-1.97,1.97-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.96.89,1.96,1.97v6.16Zm8.25,92.98c0,1.08-.88,1.97-1.96,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.89-1.97-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.89-1.97,1.97-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.96.89,1.96,1.97v6.16Zm0-15.5c0,1.09-.88,1.97-1.96,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.88-1.97-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.89-1.96,1.97-1.96h.12c1.08,0,1.96.88,1.96,1.96v6.16Zm0-15.49c0,1.08-.88,1.96-1.96,1.96h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.88-1.97-1.96v-6.17c0-1.08.89-1.96,1.97-1.96h.12c1.08,0,1.96.88,1.96,1.96v6.17Zm0-15.5c0,1.08-.88,1.97-1.96,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.89-1.97-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.89-1.97,1.97-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.96.89,1.96,1.97v6.16Zm0-15.5c0,1.08-.88,1.97-1.96,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.89-1.97-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.89-1.97,1.97-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.96.89,1.96,1.97v6.16Zm0-15.49c0,1.08-.88,1.96-1.96,1.96h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.88-1.97-1.96v-6.17c0-1.08.89-1.96,1.97-1.96h.12c1.08,0,1.96.88,1.96,1.96v6.17Zm0-15.5c0,1.08-.88,1.96-1.96,1.96h-.12c-1.08,0-1.97-.88-1.97-1.96v-6.16c0-1.08.89-1.97,1.97-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.96.89,1.96,1.97v6.16Zm8.25,92.98c0,1.08-.88,1.97-1.96,1.97h-.13c-1.08,0-1.96-.89-1.96-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.88-1.97,1.96-1.97h.13c1.08,0,1.96.89,1.96,1.97v6.16Zm0-15.5c0,1.09-.88,1.97-1.96,1.97h-.13c-1.08,0-1.96-.88-1.96-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.88-1.96,1.96-1.96h.13c1.08,0,1.96.88,1.96,1.96v6.16Zm0-15.49c0,1.08-.88,1.96-1.96,1.96h-.13c-1.08,0-1.96-.88-1.96-1.96v-6.17c0-1.08.88-1.96,1.96-1.96h.13c1.08,0,1.96.88,1.96,1.96v6.17Zm0-15.5c0,1.08-.88,1.97-1.96,1.97h-.13c-1.08,0-1.96-.89-1.96-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.88-1.97,1.96-1.97h.13c1.08,0,1.96.89,1.96,1.97v6.16Zm0-15.5c0,1.08-.88,1.97-1.96,1.97h-.13c-1.08,0-1.96-.89-1.96-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.88-1.97,1.96-1.97h.13c1.08,0,1.96.89,1.96,1.97v6.16Zm0-15.49c0,1.08-.88,1.96-1.96,1.96h-.13c-1.08,0-1.96-.88-1.96-1.96v-6.17c0-1.08.88-1.96,1.96-1.96h.13c1.08,0,1.96.88,1.96,1.96v6.17Zm0-15.5c0,1.08-.88,1.96-1.96,1.96h-.13c-1.08,0-1.96-.88-1.96-1.96v-6.16c0-1.08.88-1.97,1.96-1.97h.13c1.08,0,1.96.89,1.96,1.97v6.16Zm8.25,92.98c0,1.08-.89,1.97-1.97,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.96-.89-1.96-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.88-1.97,1.96-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.97.89,1.97,1.97v6.16Zm0-15.5c0,1.09-.89,1.97-1.97,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.96-.88-1.96-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.88-1.96,1.96-1.96h.12c1.08,0,1.97.88,1.97,1.96v6.16Zm0-15.49c0,1.08-.89,1.96-1.97,1.96h-.12c-1.08,0-1.96-.88-1.96-1.96v-6.17c0-1.08.88-1.96,1.96-1.96h.12c1.08,0,1.97.88,1.97,1.96v6.17Zm0-15.5c0,1.08-.89,1.97-1.97,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.96-.89-1.96-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.88-1.97,1.96-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.97.89,1.97,1.97v6.16Zm0-15.5c0,1.08-.89,1.97-1.97,1.97h-.12c-1.08,0-1.96-.89-1.96-1.97v-6.16c0-1.08.88-1.97,1.96-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.97.89,1.97,1.97v6.16Zm0-15.49c0,1.08-.89,1.96-1.97,1.96h-.12c-1.08,0-1.96-.88-1.96-1.96v-6.17c0-1.08.88-1.96,1.96-1.96h.12c1.08,0,1.97.88,1.97,1.96v6.17Zm0-15.5c0,1.08-.89,1.96-1.97,1.96h-.12c-1.08,0-1.96-.88-1.96-1.96v-6.16c0-1.08.88-1.97,1.96-1.97h.12c1.08,0,1.97.89,1.97,1.97v6.16Z"/>
  </g>
  <g id="Portmonaie">
    <g id="Kreditkarte">
      <path class="cls-1" d="m657.05,137.99l-32.5,27.51h-10.73l35.61-30.15c1.73-1.47,4.33-1.25,5.79.47l1.82,2.16Z"/>
      <path class="cls-1" d="m672.35,162.41l-3.65,3.09h-6.27l3.22-2.73c1.25-1.06,1.41-2.96.35-4.2l-.69-.82c-1.06-1.25-2.95-1.41-4.19-.35l-4.82,4.08c-1.18,1.01-1.38,2.76-.49,4.02h-21.51l26.83-22.71,11.71,13.83c1.46,1.73,1.25,4.33-.48,5.79Z"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Tasche">
      <path class="cls-1" d="m686.69,194.8v8.6c0,1.56-1.32,2.88-2.88,2.88h-16.75c-3.94,0-7.14-3.21-7.14-7.14s3.2-7.15,7.14-7.15h16.82c1.52,0,2.81,1.29,2.81,2.81Z"/>
      <path class="cls-1" d="m655.73,199.14c0,3.11,1.27,5.95,3.32,8,2.06,2.06,4.89,3.33,8.01,3.33h15.28v15.41c0,2.26-1.85,4.11-4.11,4.11h-76.22c-2.26,0-4.11-1.85-4.11-4.11v-52.04c0-2.25,1.85-4.1,4.11-4.1h76.22c2.26,0,4.11,1.85,4.11,4.1v13.95h-15.28c-6.24,0-11.34,5.11-11.34,11.35Z"/>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g id="Diagramm">
    <path id="Diagramm_xy" data-name="Diagramm xy" class="cls-1" d="m180.32,230.02h-94.56c-2.21,0-4-1.79-4-4v-92.6c0-2.21,1.79-4,4-4s4,1.79,4,4v88.6h90.56c2.21,0,4,1.79,4,4s-1.79,4-4,4Z"/>
    <g id="Balken">
      <rect class="cls-1" x="96.03" y="165.05" width="12.13" height="51.81" rx="3.96" ry="3.96">
        <animateTransform  attributeType="xml"
        attributeName="transform" type="scale"
        values="1,1; 1,3; 1"
        begin="0s" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" />       
    </rect>
      <rect class="cls-1" x="112.98" y="145.39" width="12.13" height="71.47" rx="3.94" ry="3.94">
        <animateTransform  attributeType="xml"
        attributeName="transform" type="scale"
        values="1,1; 1,3; 1"
        begin="0.2s" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" />       
    </rect>
      <rect class="cls-1" x="129.93" y="176.07" width="12.13" height="40.79" rx="3.94" ry="3.94">
        <animateTransform  attributeType="xml"
        attributeName="transform" type="scale"
        values="1,1; 1,3; 1"
        begin="0.4s" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" />       
    </rect>
      <rect class="cls-1" x="146.88" y="187.28" width="12.13" height="29.58" rx="3.94" ry="3.94">
        <animateTransform  attributeType="xml"
        attributeName="transform" type="scale"
        values="1,1; 1,3; 1"
        begin="0.2s" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" />       
    </rect>
      <rect class="cls-1" x="163.83" y="158.25" width="12.13" height="58.61" rx="3.92" ry="3.92">
        <animateTransform  attributeType="xml"
        attributeName="transform" type="scale"
        values="1,1; 1,3; 1"
        begin="0.4s" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" />       
    </rect>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>




begin is not limitted to time values, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/begin
